# maven dependencies error by org.apache.poi, org.apache.tika, org.jxls.jxls-poi

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi, apache-tika

I must use the org.apache.poi 4.1.2 version library. However, dependence causes errors in other libraries. Please tell me the appropriate library versions.

This is the library and version information that I have to use and error.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-java7</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Please match the version of org.apache.poi 4.1.2.

i updated pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

However, the following errors continue to occur.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType() using XLSTransformer (net.sf.jxls.transformer)
and org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.PDIFSContainerDetector.getTopLevelNames(PDIFSContainerDetector.java:354)

Comment: Without know the error it's impossible to give a hint.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType() using XLSTransformer (net.sf.jxls.transformer)

Comment: and org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.PDIFSContainerDetector.getTopLevelNames(PDIFSContainerDetector.java:354)

Comment: Using old versions of poi, and tika upgrade?

Comment: Updated to the latest version, but an error occurred in java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.userModel.Cell.getCellType()

Comment: Tika 1.28 and 2.2.1 both use POI 4.1.2.  You should be good to go with either of those.  I can't speak to the other dependencies.